# Is it possible to "hijack" an oauth2 provided that the attacker has the client id, client secret and an auth token?

Tags: android, oauth

I am relativley new to authentication procedures and came across the oauth2 protocol when implementing an android app. As I am not really aquainted with the procedure - is it possible for an attacker to access data form the server providing he is in possession of the client id, client secret and an auth token?
I'm asking this to check how necessary it is to securley hide these information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why would you ever not secure that information? And always assume it's possible when security attacks are in question.